# IoT Hub device twin query returns incorrect result on lastActivityTime property

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I've been seeing some strange behaviour in the Device Twin of the Azure IoT Hub and was wondering if anyone else ran into the same problem. I have the following device twin configuration:

[image]

Sorry, I didn't want to display the full deviceId for security reasons, but believe me, they are identical as the next query/pictureIf I query: **select id, lastActivityTime from c where deviceId = 'bad...(the rest of the deviceId)'**

Then I get the following result:

[image]

Why is the date so different?

When I literaly perform a **'select * from c where deviceId = bad...'** I get an identical JSON as when I look in the device twin itself, except for the lastActivityTime...

Any idea why the lastActivityTime is such a different date?

Comment: I can confirm this is also happening on my IoT Hub, through the Azure portal but also the C# SDK. Might be an issue worth reporting to Microsoft.

Comment: oh the date is different, let me also look-into this! Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Could you please let me know the Region of your IoT Hub ?, is it Edge device?, IoT Hub Tier Free/S1/S2 ?

Comment: Hi, the region is West Europe, it's not an edge device (IoT Hub in the cloud), and it is an S1 version.

Comment: @RensGroenveld,  We confirm there is a known issue on this and Microsoft is working to resolve this issue, please stay tuned on this thread, thanks for bringing this to our Notice!

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer,  We confirm there is a known issue on this and Microsoft is working to resolve this issue, please stay tuned on this thread, thanks for bringing this to our Notice!

Comment: Thanks Satish, if it matters: S1 westeurope, regular device.

Comment: Thank you !, I am working with the team with an incident ticket on this, will share the progress over here. I will add all these details!

Comment: @RensGroenveld, Please confirm if this is effecting your current production load? Any Severity impact?

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer, Please confirm if this is effecting your current production load? Any Severity impact?

Comment: Hi Satish, thank you for your quick help. It is affecting our production load, because we want to query multiple 'lastActivityTime's from the IoT Hub, but we can only do this by querying the devices one by one through the RegistryManager (Java Iot Hub SDK), which takes a lot of time. A device twin query would be much faster.

Comment: @RensGroenveld, We have created an incident on this, will be updating you soon on this, sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Not to worry at all :) I'm glad to see this item being picked up. Thank you

Comment: **Update:** Microsoft Team has acknowledged the incident and is actively working on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an update from Microsoft on this issue, It is recommended that we do not use 'LastActivityTime', instead, make use of EventGrid notifications for connect or disconnect notifications. Below is the quote...

> LastActivityTime is not reliable. It is currently best effort and
> sometimes may not even be updated.
>
> We recommend to customers to not rely on LastActivityTime, and to use
> EventGrid notifications for connect/disconnect notifications.
>
> We are very aware of the issue and are investigating a long term
> solution to this problem.

Hopefully, We will come up with a long-term solution for this issue, sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Hi Satish, thank you very much for the investigation. We will take a look at this, and see what we can do :)